# Resume Dataset Request

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research

Where can I find a dataset of resumes around 1000-2000 for machine learning project. Preferably good resumes of software engineers. I know this question has been asked before, but I believe there should be some dataset online hiding.

P.S. Any chance of using a Python crawler to download resumes from indeed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

try Kaggle datasets: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets
Also try the Fed's St. Louis website.